# How to link JDialog to JButton click

Tags: java, button, jbutton, jdialog

I am using window builder on eclipse and am trying to make a Button open a JDialog. I have spent many hours sifting through posts and google searches and nothing I pull up has solved my issue.

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              ApiKeyEntryDialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

The main JFrame with button.

```
private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                FrontPage window = new FrontPage();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public FrontPage() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1377, 789);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 1361, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenu mnTools = new JMenu("Tools");
    menuBar.add(mnTools);

    JMenu mnView = new JMenu("View");
    menuBar.add(mnView);

    JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
    menuBar.add(mnHelp);

    JTabbedPane MainTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    MainTabbedPane.setBounds(0, 21, 1361, 729);
    frame.getContentPane().add(MainTabbedPane);

    JPanel MainTab = new JPanel();
    MainTabbedPane.addTab("Main", null, MainTab, null);
    MainTab.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              ApiKeyEntryDialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 11, 89, 23);
    MainTab.add(btnNewButton);

    JPanel AssetsTab = new JPanel();
    MainTabbedPane.addTab("Assets", null, AssetsTab, null);

    JPanel BuyOrdersTab = new JPanel();
    MainTabbedPane.addTab("Buy Orders", null, BuyOrdersTab, null);

    JPanel SellOrdersTab = new JPanel();
    MainTabbedPane.addTab("Sell Orders", null, SellOrdersTab, null);

    JPanel JitaTab = new JPanel();
    MainTabbedPane.addTab("Jita", null, JitaTab, null);


}
```

The JDialog frame that I want to pop up when the button is pressed.

```
private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;
private JTextField textField_4;
private JTextField textField_5;
private JTextField textField_6;
private JTextField textField_7;
private JTextField textField_8;
private JTextField textField_9;
private JTextField textField_10;
private JTextField textField_11;
private JTextField textField_12;
private JTextField textField_13;
private JTextField textField_14;
private JTextField textField_15;
private JTextField textField_16;
private JTextField textField_17;
private JTextField textField_18;
private JTextField textField_19;
private JTextField textField_20;
private JTextField textField_21;
private JTextField textField_22;
private JTextField textField_23;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ApiKeyEntryDialog dialog = new ApiKeyEntryDialog();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Create the dialog.
 */
public ApiKeyEntryDialog() {
    setBounds(100, 100, 610, 803);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPanel.setLayout(null);
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Api Key Entry");
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        label.setBounds(10, 11, 107, 19);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(10);
        textField.setBounds(97, 65, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Verification Code:");
        label.setBounds(10, 68, 85, 17);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" Key ID:");
        label.setBounds(55, 43, 46, 14);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(97, 40, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_1);
    }
    {
        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        textField_2.setBounds(97, 96, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_2);
    }
    {
        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setColumns(10);
        textField_3.setBounds(97, 121, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_3);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Verification Code:");
        label.setBounds(10, 124, 85, 17);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" Key ID:");
        label.setBounds(55, 99, 46, 14);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        textField_4 = new JTextField();
        textField_4.setColumns(10);
        textField_4.setBounds(97, 152, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_4);
    }
    {
        textField_5 = new JTextField();
        textField_5.setColumns(10);
        textField_5.setBounds(97, 177, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_5);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Verification Code:");
        label.setBounds(10, 180, 85, 17);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" Key ID:");
        label.setBounds(55, 155, 46, 14);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        textField_6 = new JTextField();
        textField_6.setColumns(10);
        textField_6.setBounds(97, 208, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_6);
    }
    {
        textField_7 = new JTextField();
        textField_7.setColumns(10);
        textField_7.setBounds(97, 233, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_7);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Verification Code:");
        label.setBounds(10, 236, 85, 17);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" Key ID:");
        label.setBounds(55, 211, 46, 14);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        textField_8 = new JTextField();
        textField_8.setColumns(10);
        textField_8.setBounds(97, 264, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_8);
    }
    {
        textField_9 = new JTextField();
        textField_9.setColumns(10);
        textField_9.setBounds(97, 289, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_9);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Verification Code:");
        label.setBounds(10, 292, 85, 17);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" Key ID:");
        label.setBounds(55, 267, 46, 14);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        textField_10 = new JTextField();
        textField_10.setColumns(10);
        textField_10.setBounds(97, 320, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_10);
    }
    {
        textField_11 = new JTextField();
        textField_11.setColumns(10);
        textField_11.setBounds(97, 345, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_11);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Verification Code:");
        label.setBounds(10, 348, 85, 17);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" Key ID:");
        label.setBounds(55, 323, 46, 14);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        textField_12 = new JTextField();
        textField_12.setColumns(10);
        textField_12.setBounds(97, 376, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_12);
    }
    {
        textField_13 = new JTextField();
        textField_13.setColumns(10);
        textField_13.setBounds(97, 401, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_13);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Verification Code:");
        label.setBounds(10, 404, 85, 17);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" Key ID:");
        label.setBounds(55, 379, 46, 14);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        textField_14 = new JTextField();
        textField_14.setColumns(10);
        textField_14.setBounds(97, 432, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_14);
    }
    {
        textField_15 = new JTextField();
        textField_15.setColumns(10);
        textField_15.setBounds(97, 457, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_15);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Verification Code:");
        label.setBounds(10, 460, 85, 17);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" Key ID:");
        label.setBounds(55, 435, 46, 14);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        textField_16 = new JTextField();
        textField_16.setColumns(10);
        textField_16.setBounds(97, 488, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_16);
    }
    {
        textField_17 = new JTextField();
        textField_17.setColumns(10);
        textField_17.setBounds(97, 513, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_17);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Verification Code:");
        label.setBounds(10, 516, 85, 17);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" Key ID:");
        label.setBounds(55, 491, 46, 14);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        textField_18 = new JTextField();
        textField_18.setColumns(10);
        textField_18.setBounds(97, 544, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_18);
    }
    {
        textField_19 = new JTextField();
        textField_19.setColumns(10);
        textField_19.setBounds(97, 569, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_19);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Verification Code:");
        label.setBounds(10, 572, 85, 17);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" Key ID:");
        label.setBounds(55, 547, 46, 14);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        textField_20 = new JTextField();
        textField_20.setColumns(10);
        textField_20.setBounds(97, 600, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_20);
    }
    {
        textField_21 = new JTextField();
        textField_21.setColumns(10);
        textField_21.setBounds(97, 625, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_21);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Verification Code:");
        label.setBounds(10, 628, 85, 17);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" Key ID:");
        label.setBounds(55, 603, 46, 14);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        textField_22 = new JTextField();
        textField_22.setColumns(10);
        textField_22.setBounds(97, 656, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_22);
    }
    {
        textField_23 = new JTextField();
        textField_23.setColumns(10);
        textField_23.setBounds(97, 681, 482, 20);
        contentPanel.add(textField_23);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Verification Code:");
        label.setBounds(10, 684, 85, 17);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" Key ID:");
        label.setBounds(55, 659, 46, 14);
        contentPanel.add(label);
    }
    {
        JButton btnVerify = new JButton("Verify");
        btnVerify.setBounds(337, 712, 89, 23);
        contentPanel.add(btnVerify);
    }
    {
        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.setBounds(451, 712, 89, 23);
        contentPanel.add(btnSave);
    }
    {
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}

public static void showConfirmationDialog(boolean b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I am used to cutting and pasting VB code for macros but the Java invirontment does not act the same. Trying to modify and insert different code from examples has not worked.

Comment: You have example code in your ApiKeyEntryDialog's main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please replace the following snippet of code in `FrontPage` class:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              ApiKeyEntryDialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

by following snippet of code:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ApiKeyEntryDialog dialog = new ApiKeyEntryDialog();
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

and tell me the result?

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.